# C multiple assignments to same variable in short-circuited expression

Tags: c

I have three variables: `a`, `b`, `c`. Let's say they are integers. I want to find the first non-zero value among them, in that particular order, without looping. The following seems to work, but I am not sure if that is because I am lucky, or because the language guarantees it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 5;
    int test;

    if ((test = a) != 0 || (test = b) != 0 || (test = c) != 0) {
        printf("First non-zero: %d\n", test);
    } else {
        printf("All zero!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is the repeated assignment with short-circuiting shown here guaranteed to work as intended, or am I missing something?

This might be one place where a three-letter answer would be acceptable, but a two-letter answer might require more explanation.

Comment: I'd say it works, but is mad - makes sense though as from _Mad Physicist_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica. Be true to oneself and all... What alternative would be less mad?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: call me Crazy Charlie: `test = a + !!a * (b + !!b * c);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is very bad practice but it is guaranteed to work fine.

This is because the `||` and `&&` operators have special characteristics - unlike most operators in C, they guarantee that the evaluation of the left operand is sequenced (executed) before the evaluation of the right operand. This is the reason that the code works. There's also a guarantee that the right operand will not be evaluated if it is sufficient to evaluate the left one ("short circuit"). Summarized in C17 6.5.14/4:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
>   second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
>   and second operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.

"Sequence point" being the key here, which is what gives the expression a deterministic outcome.

Had you used pretty much any other operator (like for example bitwise `|`), then the result would be undefined, because you have multiple side effects (assignments) on the same variable `test` in the same expression.

A more sound version of the same algorithm would involve storing the data in an array and loop through it.

Answer (score 6):

It would!

> Because of the nature of the OR operator if any of the condition is
>   true then the test stops.

Thus i think what you did was basically equivalent to:

```
test = a != 0 ? a : b != 0 ? b : c != 0 ? c : 0;
printf("%d\n",test);
```

but heck yours looks good.

[update]

As per what chqrlie mentioned it can be further simplified to:

```
test = a ? a : b ? b : c;
```

Comment: FWIW, I like your alternative phrasing too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hoping to be a MadPhysicist some day in the future too haha. Thanks for the question though. Very intriguing.

Comment: The last test in your assignment is redundant. You could simply write: `test = a ? a : b ? b : c;`

Comment: @chqrlie Damn awesome catch! Thanks for letting me know of a even better solution. I had added your solution up so others can reference

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your expression is fully defined because there is a sequence point at each `||` operator and the short circuit evaluation guarantees that the first non zero value assigned to `test` completes the expression.

Here is a crazy alternative without sequence points that may produce branchless code:

```
int test = a + !!a * (b + !!b * c);
printf("%d\n", test);
```

Comment: If the purpose was just to get a zero or non-zero branch-free, you may as well just do `a*b*c`. Or perhaps `!!a * !!b * !!c` if you worry about overflows. Each `!!` is somewhat likely to result in a branch though.

Comment: @Lundin. The goal is to get the first nonzero in a particular order

Comment: @MadPhysicist And if the input is `a=0; b=3; c=3`?

Comment: Uh I guess I just invented the need for a even worse code. `int* test;` ... `if (*(test = &a) != 0 || *(test = &b) != 0 || *(test = &c) != 0) {
        printf("First non-zero: %d, it was %s\n", *test, IT_WAS(test));` with `#define IT_WAS(addr) (addr)==&a ? "a" : (addr)==&b ? "b" : "c"`.

Comment: @Lundin. In that case `b` is the first nonzero. That's a delicious approach.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That was my point, if `b=3; c=3` and you get `3` as output, you don't know how you ended up with that result. Unless you use the strongly questionably pointer code in my comment above, that is...

Comment: @MadPhysicist But if I did, someone might end up using the code!

Comment: This does evaluate `b,c` even if `a` is non-zero.  So is not the same when `b,c` are not yet assigned.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica. I agree, but that's part of the appeal.

Comment: @Lundin. It's too late for me either way. The seeds have been planted!

Comment: @MadPhysicist In that case, may I tempt you with some [questionable use of the comma operator, served together with some delicious setjmp spaghetti](https://godbolt.org/z/ezwUhW)? I'm fairly sure this code has well-defined behavior, but I would probably recommend it to pass through a code review or two before rolling it out in production.